# How to index rows like columns in Solr

Tags: solr, indexing, rows

I have a products table on my database, and a table with features of this products. The features table have 3 columns: id, type and value. Id is a foreign key from products.
A example of data on my tables:
Table Products:

ID | Description  |

01 Computer A

02 Car

03 Computer B

Table Features:

ID | Type | Value |

01 Processor Phenom X3

01 Memory    2GB

01 HDD       500GB

02 Color     Blue

02 Mark      Ford

03 Processor Phenom X3

03 Memory    3GB

I want the best way to index it, so, a example, when someone searches for “computer”, the faceting shows:

Phenom X3(2)

Memory 2GB(1)

Memory 3GB(1)

HDD 500GB(1)

And so on, related with the query string. If I make a query with the string “processor”, it will list Phenom X3(1) only if this products (with “processor” on description) have a feature like Processor: Phenom X3.  There’s a lot of product types, so we can’t create static colums to all features and pass it to Solr…
I hope my question is clear, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use data import handler to index the data @ http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler

You can define the products table as main entity and features as sub entity. So that the product with features is indexed as a single document.

For indexing -
Define description field as indexed true
As you want facet on type and value, you can define a new field type_value with type string and concat the type and value field in dataconfig.xml
type_value will be a multivalued field.

For searching - 
Make the product description field searchable e.g. q=description:computers
You can configure this in the solrconfig.xml with proper weightage

Define the features field as a facet field and facet.field=type_value

I hope this gives a fair idea.

Comment: Great, it helped a lot. I've done the concat with templatetransformer, but it seems the data under the type_value field get indexed wrong. I get "amd phenom X 3 intel I 5" (all stripped) instead of something like " Amd:Phenomx3 intel:i5". Also, there's a way to check on Solr what is indexed, like a query on DB, when rows are returned?

Comment: Ok, after some research, I find the answers: used tokenizer class solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory. This makes the concat works great (the solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory splits every whitespace).
Also, I'm using Luke to see what is indexed. I think there's another way to do that, but I'm happy with what he does. Thanks!